# ¿Como puedo detectar un cambio dentro de un array de objetos en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente array de objetos:

```
const dataUser = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Josue' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Alejandro' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Rodrigo' },
];
```

Necesito desplegar una alerta si detecta que tengo otro objeto dentro del array. No tengo ni la mas minima idea de como puedo realizarlo.

Lo que intente fue lo siguiente:

```
Array.observe(dataUser , function(changes) {
  console.log(changes);
});
```

Comment: @BetaM Si exactamente eso es lo que necesito.

Comment: @BetaM Listo ya actualize la pregunta, con lo que e intentado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma mas simple de lograrlo es:

- Lee el evento `DOMContentLoaded` del objeto `document` esto revisará cuando el *DOM* esté cargado
- Dentro de la función anónima que pasamos como segundo argumento al `addEventListener` evaluamos la propiedad `length` del array de objetos
- Si esta longitud excede el 3 entonces podemos notificarlo (*Aquí lo haces tu en la forma que resulte mas conveniente para tu desarrollo*)
- En caso contrario por ejemplo (*y solo por fines demostrativos*) podemos imprimir el array completo en tu documento HTML

```html
    <pre id="aviso"></pre>
    <script>
        let dataUser = [
          {id: 1, name: 'Josue'},
          {id: 2, name: 'Alejandro'},
          {id: 3, name: 'Rodrigo'},
        ]
    
        let longitudDataUser = dataUser.length;
        const aviso = document.getElementById("aviso");
        
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
          if (longitudDataUser > 3) {
            aviso.innerText = 'Has excedido el límite';
          } else {
            aviso.innerText = JSON.stringify(dataUser);
          }
        })
    </script>
```